# Cloud Run Container Not Building Possibly Due to Package Issue?

Tags: dependencies, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am encountering an error when I am building a Cloud Run container from a particular directory in a GCP project. This particular directory has always built correctly in the past, and no changes were made to it since the last successful build.

Recently, however, I wanted to fire up a pipeline for this directory, so I added a few pound signs to the code (so the Cloud Build trigger could start building the Run container - additionally, the addition of these pound signs should not affect anything in the code). In the process, this error showed up:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.7-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.7-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.7-dev'
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update   && apt-get upgrade -y   && apt-get install -y wget 
unzip xvfb libxtst6 libxrender1 python3.7-dev build-essential net-tools' returned a non-zero 
code: 100
```

Given that nothing changed, I'm not sure what caused this error. What could this error message mean, and what actions should I take to fix it? Any help is appreciated, and if more information is needed, I'll gladly update the question. Thanks!

EDIT: These are the dockerfile contents:

```docker
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Cloud Run logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# install dependencies
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install -y wget unzip xvfb libxtst6 libxrender1 python3.7-dev build-essential net-tools
#RUN apt-get install -y procps

# set environment variables
ENV TWS_INSTALL_LOG=/root/Jts/tws_install.log \
    ibcIni=/root/ibc/config.ini \
    ibcPath=/opt/ibc \
    javaPath=/opt/i4j_jres \
    twsPath=/root/Jts \
    twsSettingsPath=/root/Jts

# make dirs
RUN mkdir -p /tmp && mkdir -p ${ibcPath} && mkdir -p ${twsPath}

# copy over IB Gateway
COPY Jts /root/Jts
COPY i4j_jres /home/mmr/.i4j_jres

# download IBC
RUN wget -q -O /tmp/IBC.zip https://github.com/IbcAlpha/IBC/releases/download/3.8.2/IBCLinux-3.8.2.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/IBC.zip -d ${ibcPath}
RUN chmod +x ${ibcPath}/*.sh ${ibcPath}/*/*.sh

# copy IBC/Jts configs
COPY ibc/config.ini ${ibcIni}

# copy cmd script
WORKDIR /home
COPY cmd.sh cmd.sh
RUN chmod +x cmd.sh

# set display environment variable (must be set after TWS installation)
ENV DISPLAY=:0


WORKDIR /home
COPY ib_server ./ib_server
COPY __init__.py .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r /home/requirements.txt

# execute cmd script to start Xvfb and gunicorn
CMD ./cmd.sh
# CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

The container creation is triggered when a change is made to the directory and pushed, which is why I had to add the pound signs and push to fire up the build.

Comment: post your dockerfile

Comment: how do you trigger your container creation?

Comment: I have added the dockerfile and specified how the container creation is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the python3.7-dev package you are trying to install in the container (line 9 of your Dockerfile), as the package no longer exists in the sources of the container. It has nothing to do with your change, or with Cloud Build, as probably the package was just removed from the sources since the last push.

If you need a python-dev package, I would recommend that you consider installing `python3-dev` especially, or `python3.9-dev`, as all changes in minor python versions should be backwards compatible with each other.

However if you really need `python3.7-dev`, you would need to manually recompile and install the packages, or add sources where it can be found and install it then. Bear in mind that the debian version this python image is based in has incompatibilities with this package you will need to manually solve, so it wouldn't be a straight forward solution.

Comment: Do you know how it could have been removed? I don't think anyone working on this project tampered with python package settings. Also, how would I install the python3-dev package on Google Cloud Platform? Any changes to packages I make in the cloud shell are removed after I close out of it, or that's at least what I thought.

Comment: It has been removed from the source. That is usually a decision from the developers or the source maintainers, doesn't involve any tampering on your side, just an obsolete package reference in the Dockerfile. In the future I would recommend using "python3-dev" instead of a specific version such as 3.7, so it always stays up to date. This is about the Dockerfile. If this answer has worked for you, please indicate it to help other people with similar doubts

Comment: About the Google Cloud Shell, it resets so you are right about it's non-persistency, but you can install it like in a normal shell. However if you want to ask more about this, or have a specific use case you want to talk about, please open a new question and you can link it here if you want me to find it :)

Comment: Here's the link to the new question, in case any others have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930848/how-to-install-python3-dev-in-a-google-cloud-platform-project

Comment: I just checked your new question and now understand why you wanted to ask it here. What I meant with my answer was not to install python3-dev in the shell, but to change it in your Dockerfile. Line 9 in the file you posted installs `python3.7-dev` inside your container, and that is what fails to run.

Comment: wow! when I changed python3.7-dev to python3.9-dev, it worked! (for some reason, changing it to python3-dev gave an error). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it did! I have just updated the answer for more clarity. However python3-dev worked in my environment, so feel free if you want to ask a new question about this new problem about it. Nevertheless, I believe this solution should work in the mid term